# Do we know of any history between Admiral Kirsten Clancy and Picard?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

In Series One, Episode 2 (*Maps and Legends*) of *Picard*, Picard appeals to Starfleet for a ship, but is denied by Admiral Kirsten Clancy.

During their exchange, Picard admits that he and Clancy have not seen eye-to-eye in the past.

Do we know of any history between Admiral Kirsten Clancy and Picard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They rehash their old standpoints in that very scene:

> **Clancy:** The Romulans were our enemies, and we tried to help them for as long as we could, but even before the synthetics attacked Mars, fourteen species within the Federation said 'Cut the Romulans loose, or we'll pull out.' It was a choice between allowing the Federation to implode, or letting the Romulans go.
>   **Picard:** The Federation does not get to decide if a species lives or dies!
>   **Clancy:** Yes we do. We absolutely do. Thousands of other species depend upon us for unity, for cohesion. We didn't have enough ships left. We had to make choices, but the great Captain Picard didn't like his orders.
>   **Picard:** I was standing up for the Federation for what it represents! For what it should **still** represent!
>   **Clancy:** How dare you lecture me!

In essence, they have been, and are still, divided over the question whether or not the Federation has a moral obligation to help the Romulans. Picard sees this as a core value of the Federation, Clancy, not so much.

Comment: IRL, the actress ([Ann Magnuson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ann_Magnuson)) portraying Admiral Clancy was busy fronting a '[psychedelic rock group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bongwater_(band))' during the late 1980's and early 1990's when ST-TNG was being shot so I find it unlikely that she was even an uncredited extra on the show.

Comment: I just listened to "The Power of Pussy" from her band, "Bongwater".  Wow, just wow!

Comment: Yeah, I was originally a little surprised to hear the F-Bomb come out of Admiral Clancy in the middle of her conversation with Picard. Now, not so much.

Comment: @Jeeped  The question was not about previous relations between actors Patrick Stewart and Ann Magnuson, it was about previous relations between the characters  Jean-Luc Picard and Kirsten Clancy.  There is no reason to assume Kirsten Clancy could not have been played by some other actress in a previous production, or to assume that she could not have interacted with Picard off screen during a time outside of The Next Generation time frame.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - And that is why it is a comment with some supplemental background information, not posted as an answer.

Comment: She should think herself lucky she didn't meet Our Jim, interplanetary stud.